# Evaluate shell script in environment variable only once in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm using following way to evaluate a shell script and use its output as environment variable:

```
pipeline {
    agent { ... }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            environment {
                TEST_SCRIPT = "${sh(script: 'echo "This should be evaluated only once"', returnStdout: true)}"
                TEST_USAGE = "${env.TEST_SCRIPT} and ${env.TEST_SCRIPT}"
            }
            steps {
                sh 'printenv | grep TEST | sort'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works as expected and output "This should be evaluated only once" is written to env var `TEST_SCRIPT`. But when I'm using env var `TEST_SCRIPT` in other env var (e.g. `TEST_USAGE` in example), the script is evaluated multiple times:

[image: Pipeline]

Is it possible to store resulting output in `TEST_SCRIPT` instead of executing it multiple times?

Comment: That is some odd behaviour. One way to work around this could be to assign TEST_SCRIPT in a `script{}` block instead.

Comment: change to `TEST_USAGE = env.TEST_SCRIPT + " and " + env.TEST_SCRIPT`

Comment: @yong The suggested change results in error: `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: WorkflowScript: 13: Environment variable values to be concatenated together must be single or double quoted.`

Comment: @Alex, Yes you're right.  I think it will work, but not. Sorry for about that. I tried several ways, but no luck.

Comment: @yong Thank you very much, I really appreciate your effort :)

Comment: I have an idea but not verify.  `TEST_SCRIPT = sh(script: 'echo "This should be evaluated only once" > tmp.txt')`  `TEST_USAGE = "${sh(script: 'cat tmp.txt, returnStdout: true').trim()} and ${sh(script: 'cat tmp.txt, returnStdout: true').trim()}"`